# Add new rows in list of lists with conditions in R

Tags: r, for-loop, rbind

I have a list of lists `testFrame` that looks like:

```
d1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(10, 7), var2 = c(20,2), var3 = c(30,1))
d2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(20,1), var2 = c(30,2), var3 = c(40,3))
testFrame <- list(d1, d2)
```

```
[[1]]
    var1 var2 var3
  1   10   20   30
  2    7    2    1

[[2]]
    var1 var2 var3
  1   20   30   40
  2    1    2    3
```

I want to add two new rows to each list, where if it's the first column in the list, the 3rd row will be the max value between row 1 and 2, and the 4th row is the min value. Else, the third row will be the number from the fourth row in the previous column, and the fourth row is that number minus the min number from that column.

The result should look like:

```
[[1]]
    var1 var2 var3
  1   10   20   30
  2    7    2    1
  3   10    7    5
  4    7    5    4

[[2]]
    var1 var2 var3
  1   20   30   40
  2    1    2    3
  3   20    1   -1
  4    1   -1   -4
```

So far, I have

```
addRows<- lapply (testFrame,
                  function(x)
                    for(i in 1:3) {
                     if (i==1) {rbind.......}
                     else {
                       rbind(.........)
                     }
                    }
                   )
```

I'm getting stuck at what to put in the rbind.

Comment: Can you provide your list so I can use them as an example ?

Comment: Use `dput(x)` to provide your data

Answer (score 1):

```
my_df <- data.frame("var1" = c(10, 7),
                "var2" = c(20, 2),
                "var3" = c(30, 1),
                "var4" = c(40, 7),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df2 <- data.frame("var1" = c(10, 18),
                 "var2" = c(20, 2),
                 "var3" = c(30, 1),
                 "var4" = c(40, 7),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df3 <- data.frame("var1" = c(10, 20),
                 "var2" = c(20, 2),
                 "var3" = c(30, 1),
                 "var4" = c(40, 7),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_list <- list(my_df, my_df2, my_df3)

my_third <- function(x, y) {
if (x == 1) {
my_result <- max(my_list[[y]]$var1)
} else if (x == 2) {
my_result <- my_list[[y]][2, 1]
} else {
my_result <- my_list[[y]][2, x - 2] - my_list[[y]][2, x - 1]
}
return (my_result)
}
my_fourth <- function(x, y) {
if (x == 1) {
my_result <- min(my_list[[y]]$var1)
} else {
my_result <- my_list[[y]][3, x] - my_list[[y]][2, x]
}
return (my_result)
}
my_f <- function(y) {
my_a <- lapply(1:ncol(my_list[[y]]), function(x) my_third(x, y))
my_list[[y]] <<- rbind(my_list[[y]], my_a)
my_a <- lapply(1:ncol(my_list[[y]]), function(x) my_fourth(x, y))
my_list[[y]] <<- rbind(my_list[[y]], my_a)
}
my_list2 <- lapply(1:length(my_list), my_f)
my_list2[[1]]
my_list2[[2]]
my_list2[[3]]
```

Edit: Change the code so it can handle a list of dataframe

Comment: How would this work if there are multiple columns? That's why I put the for loop, so I wouldn't need to hard code the numbers in.

Comment: Well that depends on what you're expecting how should it work if you have 4 columns like what is the pattern if you tell me then I'll be able to generalize it

Comment: If you look at my resulting matrix above, I've shown the pattern. I've also written it out

Comment: How would I perform this calculation on a list of data frames?